# Partitioned pcap file

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap

I received a network traffic capture that is partitioned is several hundred of small .pcap files with the following format:

```
name.pcap#
```

where # is a numeration from 1 to 630.
Something like this:

```
name.pcap1,name.pcap2,name.pcap3,...,name.pcap630
```

I know that all of them are from one continue capture but it seems that was partitioned.
I don't have a lot experience working with wireshark, and this type of files are new for me. I don't know how to read them as one file.

I was wondering what can I do to resemble all of them in just one file?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering what can I do to resemble all of them in just one file?

At least with the current version of Wireshark, if you:

1. start Wireshark without opening a file - just directly start the application;
2. select all 630 of the files in Windows Explorer/File Explorer (Windows), the Finder (macOS), or whatever file manager you are using in the GUI (other UN*Xes - Linux, *BSD, Solaris, AIX, etc.);
3. drag them into Wireshark;

Wireshark should read all the files and combine them into a single file, showing you all the packets.

I tested this on macOS; I have not tested it on Windows or, for example, Ubuntu, but I suspect it would work.

Note that you must select *all* the files and drag them *all* in one operation; if you try to drag them one at a time, they won't be combined, Wireshark will just close the currently open one and open the file that you're dragging and dropping.

Alternatively, Wireshark includes [mergecap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html), which is a tool that "merges two or more capture files into one".

It is a command-line tool, so you will have to use it on the command line (UN*X - Linux, macOS, *BSD, Solaris, AIX, etc. - or Windows).

The command would be something such as

```
mergecap name.pcap* -w merged.pcap
```

(on UN*Xs) or

```
mergecap.exe name.pcap* -w merged.pcap
```

if you were to run it while your command-line shell is in the directory (folder) in which the files are stored.  This command will put a new file, named `merged.pcap`, in that directory.

You will have to make sure that the directory containing mergecap is in your command-line shell's search path, or will have to type the full pathname rather than just `mergecap`.  (The `.exe` may not be necessary on Windows with some command-line shells, but it doesn't hurt, and may be necessary with other command-line shells.)

On most UN*Xes, `mergecap` will probably be in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`, both of which are in the command-line shell search path by default.

On macOS, `mergecap` will probably be in `/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/`; however, if, when you installed Wireshark, you chose to install the Wireshark command-line tools, it will also be in `/usr/local/bin`, which is, again, in the command-line shell search path by default.

On Windows, `mergecap` will probably be in `C:\Windows\Program Files\Wireshark`.  That is probably *not* in the command-line shell search path by default.  If you don't put it in your command-line shell search path, you will have to run a command such as

```
`"C:\Windows\Program Files\Wireshark\mergecap.exe" name.pcap* -w merged.pcap
```

Adding it to the command-line shell search path is a painful process, so it's probably easier just to use the full path.

You must include the quote characters (because there's a space in "Program Files").